# Alias for column names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my database has column names such as 'delete' or 'listen-control' and so on. These cannot be changed, so I would like to alias the names so as to avoid problems in my application.

I found [the following code](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/556) but it is outdated (05 Aug 2005) and doesn't work with Rails 3:

```
module Legacy
  def self.append_features(base)
    super
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def alias_column(options)
      options.each do |new_name, old_name|
        self.send(:define_method, new_name) { self.send(old_name) }
        self.send(:define_method, "#{new_name}=") { |value| self.send("#{old_name}=", value) }
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  include Legacy
end
```

How can I alias the column names? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with using 'delete' and 'listen-control' as column names? Do you run into an error or something else?

Comment: listen-control causes problems because it has a dash in the name, which makes it an invalid ruby object attribute.  Ruby will interpret "object.listen-control" as "object.listen, minus control".  And delete might be a reserved keyword.  I don't know why you'd want to do this.  Sometimes the right answer is to stop trying to fight ruby or rails.

Comment: `define_method("listen-control", Proc.new { puts "bingo" })` then `send("listen-control")`. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 175):

Declare this in your model.

```
alias_attribute :new_column_name, :column_name_in_db
```

Comment: This method doesn't work when a table column has a name with a dash in it.  The table column has to map to a valid ruby method name as-is, to be able to use this.

Comment: would this work?

`alias_attribute :'new-column-name', :'column-name-in-db'`

Comment: :'foo' is identical to :foo.  :'new-column-name' is a Symbol. I suppose you didn't try it. ;)

Comment: Note: Arel isn't going to pay attention to this.

Comment: p.s. this only changed the method alias, if you have code like `User.where("login like ?", params[:login])`, you have to change it(the login here) to the new column name yourself.

Comment: I wish Django had this.

Comment: This does not work for cache_key. `alias_attribute :last_modified_time, :updated_at` does not generate the cache_key based on the last modified timestamp.

Comment: Update from 2017: Arel still doesn't pay attention to this.

Answer (score 12):

Aliasing method names won't solve your problem.  As I mentioned in my comment above, you can't have dashes in ruby method or variable names, because ruby will interpret them as a "minus".  so:

```
object.listen-control
```

will be interpreted by ruby as:

```
object.listen - control
```

and will fail.  The code snippet you found might be failing because of ruby 1.9, not rails 3.  Ruby 1.9 doesn't let you call `.send` on protected or private methods anymore, like 1.8 used to.

That being said, I do understand there are times when old database column names don't look very nice, and you want to clean them up. Create a folder in your lib folder called "bellmyer".  Then create a file called "create_alias.rb", and add this:

```
module Bellmyer
  module CreateAlias
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend CreateAliasMethods
    end

    module CreateAliasMethods
      def create_alias old_name, new_name
        define_method new_name.to_s do
          self.read_attribute old_name.to_s
        end

        define_method new_name.to_s + "=" do |value|
          self.write_attribute old_name.to_s, value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your model that needs aliasing, you can do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Bellmyer::CreateAlias
  create_alias 'name-this', 'name_this'
end
```

And it will alias properly.  It's using the `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods of ActiveRecord to access those table columns without calling them as ruby methods.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm tested your solution and get error:

SyntaxError (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:229: syntax error, unexpected ','
              send(:vm-password=, *args)
                                 ^):

when defined: alias_attribute "vm_password", "vm-password"

and try to get "vm_password".

Comment: Big thanks!
I tested it and finds:

1. In user.rb needs add first line: require 'bellmyer/create_alias.rb'

2. When no one records in table, your method works fine. With one or more records rails gets error: ActionView::Template::Error (/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:273: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting keyword_end undef :vm-password?…

3. With field name such as 'delete' this method not works because 'delete' is method name.

Comment: You can't use the old field names in your view.  In my example above, you need to use "<%= user.name_this %>".  You also need to custom_alias your delete field, and give it a different name.  If you alias it to "delete_field" then you can call "<%= user.delete_field %>".

Comment: I'm used new names of course.
My migration: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281427/

My controller: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281428/

My model: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281430/

My view: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281433/

Error: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281434/

Erro for enable in migration and aliased 'delete': http://paste.pocoo.org/show/281439/

Sorry for many pastes.

Comment: +1 for a nice solution using the '.' operator but

>>  you can't have dashes in ruby method or variable names

Isn't completely correct. You can have methods with -'s if you escape them and use send like so object.send(:'method-with-dashes').

Comment: Nice solution, but provides inaccurate information.

Comment: This is false: *"Ruby 1.9 doesn't let you call `.send` on protected or private methods anymore"*.  On 2.3 and 2.4 `.send` works just fine for private methods.  Perhaps `.public_send` was involved?

Answer (score 0):

As Jaime said, those names might cause problems.

In that case, use some sensible names. Your GUI should never dictate how your columns are named.

Suggestions: `is_deleted` or `deleted_at`, `listen_control`

Then, change your view accordingly, that's way easier than fighting ActiveRecord and your database.

Comment: … and change main application which reads and writes in/from database with only this names?