# Override attributes keys in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model `Post` with an attribute `published_at`.
However, in POST request API requires it to be assigned as `published`, not `published_at`.
So in my model I override setter method like so

```
def published=(value)
  self.published_at = value
end
```

The problem is, in my API tests, I use FactoryGirl's `attributes_for(:post)` method to generate attributes for POST request, and it uses old `published_at` name. How can I workaround this problem and generate attributes with `published` key instead of `published_at` without changing the name of this attribute in my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing your `:post` factory:

```
factory :post do
  published { Time.now }
  # published_at
end
```

Or, if you want to separate API and Web based posts, create a new factory:

```
factory :api_post, class: Post do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I can create a new factory for the same class, works great.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried this myself, but it seems like an alias might work:

```
alias_attribute :published, :published_at
```

And in that case I would probably get rid of `Post#published=`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4017071/199712