# Is it possible to alias to_s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alias, alias-method

Instead of overriding `to_s` in my model I'd like to alias it to an existing method called `full_name`.

Both `alias` and `alias_method` don't seem to work as expected.

#### Using `alias`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ... other model code.

  alias to_s full_name

  def full_name
     "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

# In Terminal
> Person.last.to_s  #=> "#<Person:0x007fa5f8a81b50>"
```

#### Using `alias_method`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ... other model code.

  alias_method :to_s, :full_name

  def full_name
     "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

# In Terminal
> Person.last.to_s  #=> "#<Person:0x007fa5f8a81b50>"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out...

**`alias` and `alias_method` need to come *after* the method you are aliasing to.**

So both of the following work fine:

#### Using `alias`

```
class Person
  def full_name
     "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  alias to_s full_name
end

# In Terminal
> Person.last.to_s  #=> "Don Draper"
```

#### Using `alias_method`

```
class Person
  def full_name
     "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  alias_method :to_s, :full_name
end

# In Terminal
> Person.last.to_s  #=> "Don Draper"
```

*Hopefully that helps somebody else.*

Comment: I was literally halfway through the question when I was like, "Riiiiiiiiight...". Figured I'd finish what I started. If it saves somebody 10 seconds, it's worth the post.

Comment: The important thing to note here is the `alias_method` call takes effect with whatever methods are declared *at that point* of evaluation. This means you can alias a method you subsequently override, preserving the original behaviour without the original name.

Comment: @tadman Now that's a proper explanation, thanks for adding that comment.

Comment: I have the same problem but want to alias an ActiveRecord model attribute, like first_name, so I don't have the definition beforehand :/

Comment: @MegaTux I would have guessed that `alias_method` should work for that. Did you try it?

Comment: @MegaTux Try `alias_attribute :new_column_name, :column_name_in_db` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014831/alias-for-column-names-in-rails

Comment: alias_attribute worked, thx @JoshPinter !  (   alias_attribute :to_s, :name )