# private method `catch' called for Hotel (ruby 2.1 rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a column named `catch` in `hotels` table.

I created an object:

```
obj_hotel = Hotel.new
```

and then :

```
obj_hotel.catch = 'xxx'
```

**Error occurred when I did the following thing:**

```
puts obj_hotel.catch
```

There is no problem when `obj_hotel.catch` at the left of `=`, but when we want to use the value of `obj_hotel.catch`, I get the error `private method 'catch' called for Hotel` happened.

So, is `catch` a **private method** of rails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`Kernel#catch` is a private method, and `Kernel` is present in the ancestor chain of all objects that descent (including) `Object`.

Comment: For I can not edit the DataBase to change the name of the column

Comment: rename column or alias it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014831/alias-for-column-names-in-rails :)

Comment: By the way, is there any way to make the program check value or function defined by me first?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it would definitely seem so. As pointed out by azlazarov, `Kernel#catch` is a private method. You should avoid having column-names matching with ruby reserved names. So if possible rename the column (migrate the database).

If that is not possible, there is an easy workaround, you can always use

```
obj_hotel["catch"]
```

to get or set an attribute.

You can also alias an attribute name, using

```
alias_attribute :new_column_name, :catch
```

which is a very clean solution, but also potentially dangerous/confusing, imho, because when writing queries (in arel, e.g. a `where`) you will have to refer to `catch` instead of your alias).