# Rails: Is there any way to rename columns without modifying the controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to rename the columns in a Rails project, and I generated migration files and `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Procedures are like this.

generate file,

```
bin/rails g migration RenameUserTwitterNameToName
```

and write the method with column names,

```
def change
  rename_column :users, :twitter_name, :name
end
```

finally execute the rake task.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Although it works well, I need to modify the controllers related to the columns.

For example, if there is a code like below, I need to change the method `find_by_twitter_name` to `find_by_name`

```
@user = User.find_by_twitter_name(name)
```

Is there any way to modify the controller like above automatically?

Comment: No. You have to search through your project for references to old column and modify them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alias for column names in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014831/alias-for-column-names-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to modify the controller automatically, but you can make aliases for attributes, which includes getter, setter, and query methods.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    alias_attribute :twitter_name, :name
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute